# How to describe the type so that when a certain key is entered, another key is allowed

Tags: typescript

Sorry my English, could you please tell me how to describe the type so that when a certain key is entered, another key is allowed to be entered?

```
interface Base {
  top?: number;
  left?: number;
  behavior?: "auto" | "smooth"
}

interface OffsetTopProps {
  offsetTop?: number;
}

interface OffsetLeftProps {
  offsetLeft?: number;
}

// in case when top was filled, we can enter offsetTop?: number; similarly with left
```

I tried to do it with the union, but it doesn't work.

```
type test = Base | OffsetTopProps | OffsetLeftProps
```

Comment: Could you show us some assignments (`const x: Test = {/*...*/;}`) that you would A) like to have work, and B) would like **not** to have work?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbvqbm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz your answer is right, thank you so much )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enforce that when `top` is absent, then `offsetTop` must also be absent, then you can represent that portion of the type as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like this:

```
type Top = 
  { top: number, offsetTop?: number } | 
  { top?: never, offsetTop?: never };
```

TypeScript doesn't really have a direct way to prohibit a property key in an object type, but you can get close by saying that the key is an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose value is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Since there are no values of type `never`, the only reasonable thing you can do is leave the property out (or maybe set it to `undefined`).  So `Top` either has a `top` property of type `number` and an optional `offsetProperty` also of type `number`, or it has neither a `top` nor an `offsetTop` property.

Similarly for the `left`/`offsetLeft` pair:

```
type Left = 
  { left: number, offsetLeft?: number } | 
  { left?: never, offsetLeft?: never };
```

And now you can combine those with `Base` to get `Test`:

```
interface Base {
  behavior?: "auto" | "smooth"
}

type Test = Base & Top & Left;
```

Since `Test` is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `Base`, `Top`, and `Left`, a value of type `Test` must conform to all three definitions.

Let's test it out:

```
let t: Test;    
t = { behavior: "auto", top: 1 }; //okay
t = { top: 1, offsetTop: 2 }; // okay
t = { top: 1, offsetTop: 2, left: 3 }; // okay
t = { top: 1, offsetTop: 2, left: 3, offsetLeft: 4 }; // okay
t = { left: 3 }; // okay
t = { left: 3, offsetLeft: 4 }; // okay

t = { offsetTop: 2 }; // error
t = { offsetLeft: 4 }; // error
t = { top: 1, offsetTop: 2, offsetLeft: 4 }; // error
```

Looks good.  The compiler allows valid values, but rejects invalid values containing an `offsetTop` with no `top` or an `offsetLeft` with no `left`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnIBGEAFnAG7AD2UA-AFzIBEcArmFU8gD7MYC2VKmBJNcAX1xgAngAcUAFSqzkAXmTZkHWYxCt+xKABpkVGDCxglshsj0HoycTw1bltkBHLQTZixCt3XS9HcQBuKTkUABkIGDA1VwAbOLBdfUNfc0tY+I8M0JdNFLzg72NTbIDcsA8QqCcIyPlkBQgMBPV0LGQAMlblPuQaiJSEtNb2sCbO12IyShpGFnZOE21GAEZG5AB6XaoAazhpKUTNDeRNrP9AnWQAJh3902PT2YvlLZvLa0YHkwlCYAZmeu1eJzO6k+92ulVuf0egNSjGBP2qKOQABYwRD3udkEDUbijpCPoTMWj4TlMTjwntwaTTlDXH5fl9HrjoFAaCzNGyMfFGHSwgzkNzeeTLnCBXd-uiwDVhVyoDyoLhcEA)